# Unable to open the app in flutter but it is getting installed

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

There are 2 android apps in the firebase project. I want it to access one app.I changed the package name in the build.gradle and the package name is also correct.
After,the changes am getting the below error. How to resolve it ??

Below error am getting:-

I changed the pacckage name and it was correct yet unable to open the flutter app

```
E/AndroidRuntime(27385): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(27385): Process: com.tis.tis_root, PID: 27385
E/AndroidRuntime(27385): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.tis.tis_root/com.tis.tis_root.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.tis.tis_root.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList\[\[zip file "/data/app/\~\~biRvmKsCdAVdqrEFB9fN6A==/com.tis.tis_root-E9f7gEaJHF3Cy7QSfZfH3A==/base.apk"\],nativeLibraryDirectories=\[/data/app/\~\~biRvmKsCdAVdqrEFB9fN6A==/com.tis.tis_root-E9f7gEaJHF3Cy7QSfZfH3A==/lib/arm64, /data/app/\~\~biRvmKsCdAVdqrEFB9fN6A==/com.tis.tis_root-E9f7gEaJHF3Cy7QSfZfH3A==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64\]\]
E/AndroidRuntime(27385):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3681)
E/AndroidRuntime(27385):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3938)
E/AndroidRuntime(27385):        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
E/AndroidRuntime(27385):        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(27385):        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(27385):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2291)
E/AndroidRuntime(27385):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(27385):        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
E/AndroidRuntime(27385):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
E/AndroidRuntime(27385):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8319)
E/AndroidRuntime(27385):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(27385):        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)  
E/AndroidRuntime(27385):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
E/AndroidRuntime(27385): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.tis.tis_root.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList\[\[zip file "/data/app/\~\~biRvmKsCdAVdqrEFB9fN6A==/com.tis.tis_root-E9f7gEaJHF3Cy7QSfZfH3A==/base.apk"\],nativeLibraryDirectories=\[/data/app/\~\~biRvmKsCdAVdqrEFB9fN6A==/com.tis.tis_root-E9f7gEaJHF3Cy7QSfZfH3A==/lib/arm64, /data/app/\~\~biRvmKsCdAVdqrEFB9fN6A==/com.tis.tis_root-E9f7gEaJHF3Cy7QSfZfH3A==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64\]\]
E/AndroidRuntime(27385):        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
E/AndroidRuntime(27385):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime(27385):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime(27385):        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)  
E/AndroidRuntime(27385):        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
E/AndroidRuntime(27385):        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1274)
E/AndroidRuntime(27385):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3668)
E/AndroidRuntime(27385):        ... 12 more
```